# Mongoose NodeJS Schema with array of ref's

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, ref

I know there is allot's of answers about it but still I didn't quite get the idea.
I have `CourseSchema`:

```
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
course_name: String,
course_number: {type: String, unique : true },
enrolledStudents:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Student' }]
});
```

And a `StudentSchema`:

```
const StudentSchema = new Schema({
first_name: String,
last_name: String,
enrolledCourses:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'CourseSchema'
    }]
});
```

I want to reffer `enrolledStudents` at `CourseSchema` with a student, and `enrolledCourses` at `StudentSchema` with a course.

```
router.post('/addStudentToCourse', function (req, res) {
Course.findById(req.params.courseId, function(err, course){
    course.enrolledStudents.push(Student.findById(req.params.studentId, function(error, student){
        student.enrolledCourses.push(course).save();
    })).save();
});
});
```

but when posting I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'enrolledStudents' of null

---

Ok so after readying [Query-populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) I did that:

```
router.post('/addStudentToCourse', function (req, res) {

    Course.
    findOne({ _id : req.body.courseId }).
    populate({
        path: 'enrolledStudents'
        , match: { _id : req.body.studentId }
    }).
    exec(function (err, course) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log('The course name is %s', course.course_name);
    });
});
```

And when i'm hitting POST on postman I get on the console:

> The course name is intro for cs

but it is loading for ever and later on console I get:

> POST /courses/addStudentToCourse - - ms - -

Comment: in your `const CourseSchema = new ...` declaration, try changing `ref: 'Student'` to `ref: 'StudentSchema'`. Not sure, but might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the populate instruction. For example:

[see more about it here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
Course.
  findOne({ courseId : req.params.courseId }).
  populate('enrolledStudents').
  exec(function (err, course) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The course name is %s', course.name);

  });
```

It is working by using the ref field that "knows" how to populate withput using the push syntax.  it is like a foreign key population.

Just call the populate method on the query and an array of documents will be returned in place of the original _ids. you can learn more on the internals of the populate methods [in the official docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate)

Comment: Ok, I undrstend the push and populate but how do I choose the spicifice student?

Comment: the course has a list of refs to the students.  so if you add id at the ref fields of students then it will automagically fill for you the relevant students for this course.